# Training and Testing set with createFolds function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, r-caret

I tried to calculate some linear regression performance measures manually, and I want to split my [data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/yacht+hydrodynamics) using **30 folds** cross-validation.

Those performance measures need training and testing set to be calculated.

I run the following code but it gives me an error ("incompatible dimensions, longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length").

Is there a way to solve this problem using `createFolds` function?

```
######### Upload the data set #########

wdbc <- read.delim("yacht_hydrodynamics.data",sep = "",header = FALSE) 
wdbc[] <- lapply(wdbc, scale)
wdbc<-as.data.frame(wdbc)

############## Leave One Out Cross Validation split ###########

k=30
fitted_value <- rep(0,k)

for(i in 1:k){
test<-wdbc[i,]
training<-wdbc[-i,]

m=lad(V7 ~ ., data=training, method="BR")

co.data = coef(m)  
x = cbind(1, as.matrix(test[, !(colnames(test) %in% "V7")]))

fitted_value[i] <- x %*% co.data

}

 R2<-(cor(wdbc$V7,fitted_value)^2) ### R-squared
 SAD<-sum(abs(wdbc$V7 - fitted_value)) ### Sum Absloute Deviation

 c(round(SAD,2) ,round(R2,2))
```

**NOTE**

"V7" is the dependent variable.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @jcken, It gives me "incompatible dimensions, longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

Comment: do you know which line this corresponds to? If it's in the for loop copy the for loop into a new r script (same session), set i = 1 and look for where the code stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is coming from this line:

```
R2<-(cor(wdbc$V7,fitted_value)^2)
```

If you look at the data.frame you read in:

```
wdbc = read.delim("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00243/yacht_hydrodynamics.data",sep="",header=FALSE)
 dim(wdbc)
[1] 308   7
```

So subtracting a vector of 30 values from a vector of 308 doesn't work

Not very sure whether the idea is to do 30 fold cross-validation or leave 1 out, the code you have above is leave one out, and you should set `k = nrow(wdbc)` for leave-one-out . Below is a suggestion for 30 fold:

```
k=30
foldidx = split(sample(nrow(wdbc)),1:nrow(wdbc) %% k)
fitted_value <- vector("list",k)

for(i in 1:k){
test<-wdbc[foldidx[[i]],]
training<-wdbc[-foldidx[[i]],]

m=lad(V7 ~ ., data=training, method="BR")

co.data = coef(m)  
x = cbind(1, as.matrix(test[, !(colnames(test) %in% "V7")]))

fitted_value[[i]] <- x %*% co.data

}
```

Last part to match up the values, you unlist the indices, and also the list of fitted values stored:

```
obs = wdbc$V7[unlist(foldidx)]
test = unlist(fitted_value)

R2<-(cor(obs,test)^2)
```